# How can I generate tetrahedrons from the Delaunay triangulation of 3D points in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, 3d, delaunay

I need to do Delaunay Triangulation for a set of 3D points. I wrote an script for it (below), but it seems to that the output has no tetrahedrons in them. Please give me some inputs/ideas. I am using Python3. Thank you very much.

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
points= np.array([[1,2,2],[1,3,6],[4,3,4],[5,3,2]])
tri= Delaunay(points)
fig= plt.figure()
ax= fig.gca(projection= '3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(points[:,0],points[:,1],points[:,2],triangles= tri.simplices)
plt.plot(points[:,0],points[:,1],points[:,2],'+')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tetrahedrons are given in the `tri.simplices` member, which holds an `n x 4` array of indices (n being the number of tetrahedrons). The tetrahedron is given as a set of four indices, which correspond to the indices of the four points of the tetrahedron in the `points` array.

For example the following code will plot the wireframe of the first tetrahedron:

```
tr = tri.simplices[0]  # indices of first tetrahedron
pts = points[tr, :]  # pts is a 4x3 array of the tetrahedron coordinates

# plotting the six edges of the tetrahedron
for ij in [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]:
    ax.plot3D(pts[ij, 0], pts[ij, 1], pts[ij, 2])
```

See my previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284599/9702190), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263512/9702190) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65829475/9702190) for further example code.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to generate the tetrahedrons. But could you please elaborate what the last two lines do?

Comment: They plot the 3d line segments of the tetrahedron. Each of the combinations [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3] represents an edge of a tetrahedron (e.g., [0, 1] is the edge between vertex 0 of the tetrahedron and vertex 1) so the plot3D function plots a 3D line segment between the corresponding pts. Have a look at the other answers I referenced, which give more elaborate explanations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answers were very helpful, including the ones that you referred to.